# Bash script with redirect input and sleep.

Tags: bash, unix, redirect, sleep

I have a file with input commands I would like to redirect into a program like so

input.txt

```
input1
input2
input3
input4
```

I would like to redirect this into the input of a program like so

```
program < input.txt
```

But there has to be a delay between check input, based on the like number or it should sleep for about 500 milliseconds in between check input.

Comment: Can you tell *why* you need the delay?

Comment: The program must wait about half a second to get a response from another program before it can do what the next input is requesting.

Comment: can you tell what program it is?

Comment: Its a game, where each input should be delayed by a little.

Comment: Ok, then I assume that the program is using `select()` on `stdin`. So @Barmar 's answer should work well. But you should call `program` like `stdbuf -i0 program` to disable libc buffering. buffering will happen as it's not called from a tty

Answer (score 3):

```
while read input
do echo "$input"
   sleep 1
done < input.txt | program
```

Some implementations of `sleep` allow fractional seconds, but that's not portable.

Comment: Nice script +1. But, I maybe wrong, but does the delay matter? stdin is buffered anyway by the libc when called from script (and not from a tty). Am I wrong?

Comment: @hek2mgl Buffering is relevant for output, not input. I believe the shell flushes output between each command.

Comment: take the `yes` command for example. Never heard about a delay that would matter.

Comment: @hek2mgl That sounds like a question you should ask the OP, why he needs to slow down the input.

Comment: Adding the sleep was relevant for me to avoid getting booted out of an ssh session (to Cisco ASA). did inline like - while read x ; do sleep .5 ; echo $x ; done <<eof | ssh admin@10.0.0.1
>en
>passwd
>conf t
>int gi0/1
>desc "some comment"
>end
>wr
>exit
>eof

Answer (score 1):

Adding the sleep was relevant for me to avoid getting booted out of an interactive ssh session (to Cisco ASA). Did in-line here document (heredoc) like so:

```
while read x ; do sleep .5 ; echo $x ; done <<eof | ssh admin@10.0.0.1
en
passwd
conf t
int gi0/1
desc foo bar
end
wr
exit
eof
```

Output the ssh to null if you wish:

```
while read x ; do sleep .5 ; echo $x ; done <<eof | ssh admin@10.0.0.1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

It beats "expect" IMHO!